# Character swapping

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I'm trying to swap the first and last character in a string so what I did was I was able to retrieve its first and last characters but am now having hard times putting them all together:

```
   String name="pera";
   char[] c = name.toCharArray();
   char first = c[0];
   char last = c[c.length-1];
   name.replace(first, last);
   name.replace(last, first);
   System.out.println(name);
```

Although I am getting for the variable 'first' the value of "p" and for the variable 'last' the value of "a", these methods replace() are not turning up with a valid result as the name stays as it is. Does anyone have any idea on how to finish this?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you'll have to get a reference to the `String` returned by the `replace` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the first with the last is easy like this:

```
String str = "SwapDemo";
String swapped = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + str.charAt(0);
```

The method you tried will replace **all** the occurrences of the passed argument, which is not what you want. The code above will do what you want.

As Arnoud pointed out, strings are immutable. But, fixing that issue, you will still get wrong results for:

```
acbbc
```

for example

Comment: thank you sir, this is by far the easiest and most comfortable way to go along with.

Answer (score 7):

**1)** String are **immutable** in Java. so `name.replace(first, last)` will not modify `name` but will return a new String.

**2)** [String#replace(char oldChar, char newChar)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)  replaces all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

For example:

```
System.out.println("aaaddd".replace("a","d"));
```

Will give :

```
dddddd
```

**Possible solution** : If you convert your `String` to a `char[]`, you can easily swap the characters :

```
public static String inverseFirstAndLast(String str){
  char[] c = str.toCharArray();
  Character temp = c[0];
  c[0] = c[c.length-1];
  c[c.length-1]=temp;
  return new String(c);
}
```

Comment: I still say non-void functions not assigned to something should throw a compile error.

Comment: @sanbhat I am preparing a more complete answer because the OP's made a 2nd error `name.replace` will replace *all* occurences of `first` in the String.

Comment: @sanbhat this should be enough to get him moving in the right direction. However he is going to run into a problem with    name.replace(first, last);
   name.replace(last, first);

Answer (score 1):

```
 c[0] = last;
 c[c.length-1] = first;
 System.out.println(new String(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex based solution:

```
String str = "demo";
String swapped = str.replaceAll("^(.)(.*)(.)$", "$3$2$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to solution of @Martijn Courteaux. You can also store the result inside same `str` String hence saving a little bit of space, like this:

```
String str = "pera";
String str = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + str.substring(1, str.length() - 1) + str.charAt(0);
```